# C# Xunit code: End-of-file expected error. Cannot for the life of me figure out what the cause of this is

Tags: c#, testing

I'm currently trying to learn the C# fundamentals through Pluralsight and I'm currently at the Test Runner tutorial. I'm getting two problems which for the life of me I can't figure out, as it looks to me like I have the open/close brackets in all the right places.
They say:

```
Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [GradeBook.Tests] csharp(CS1022) [26, 6]
Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [GradeBook.Tests] csharp(CS1022) [27, 1]
```

And the code I'm trying to compile is:

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace GradeBook.Tests
{
    public class BookTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            //arrange
            var book = new Book("");
            book.AddGrade(89.1);
            book.AddGrade(90.5);
            book.AddGrade(77.3);

            //act
            var result = book.GetStatistics();

            //assert
            Assert.Equal(85.6, result.Average);
            Assert.Equal(90.5, result.High);
            Assert.Equal(77.3, result.Low);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm probably missing something super obvious but I'm really struggling to figure out exactly what it is.

Much appreciated!

Comment: May be it's not this file. It's definitely missing or extra closing brace for namespaces which is not matching opening curly brace.

Comment: Cut this code out, do you still get the error? - [Process of elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_of_elimination#:~:text=Process%20of%20elimination%20is%20a,by%20excluding%20all%20other%20entities.) "*Process of elimination is a logical method to identify an entity of interest among several ones by excluding all other entities.*"

Comment: The compiler is complaining about [line, col]  ; [26, 6] [27, 1]. It looks like the code you copied has 26 lines... are there unprintable characters at the end of the file?? Maybe look at it in a hex editor. Or try to select everything after the last } and delete it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this vendettamit, I'm not sure what file it could be. It references this file in the "problems" section in Visual Studio, and I've checked my other files in the project and all their braces are correct.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman 

Even if I cut the code out the error changes to the last line in the code. I've tried erasing the last lines and retyping them but the error still persists. I thought it was odd it references a 27th line too even though there's only 26 lines.

Comment: There should be no code if you cut the entire file out

Comment: @TheGeneral Unfortunately if I cut out the code it just jumps to what the new last line of code is, very strange.

Edit: Ahh sorry I misunderstood, if I cut the entire thing out I get the same error message but referencing new (non existing) lines of code

```
Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [GradeBook.Tests] cssharp(CS1022) [1,5]
Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [GradeBook.Tests] cssharp(CS1022) [2,1]
```

Comment: So ctrl+A and Ctrl+X, and you still get an error. If so it seems like your obj cache is out of wack, or a resharper cache or something. I would consider, closing down the solution delete bin and obj directories, and restart then rebuild. I would also suggest suspending and resuming resharper if you have it (unlikely to work, but worth a shot), or just delete the file and start again

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you so much, deleting bin and obj and rebuilding worked perfectly. I'll keep this in mind for the future. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I know, I am pretty awesome right... :) ill be here all week, be sure to catch the next show

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add *Resolved* or *Solved* to the title or to edit a solution into the question. If you've found a solution you want to share, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.